# front-end configurable products from simple products in magento?

Tags: magento, configurable, product

a client has imported 1000 items to magento as simple products. many of these SHOULD be configurable products (ie, 4 yellow dresses of different sizes).  the psuedo-configurable products all have the same "Style" number, so our 4 yellow dresses would have different SKU values but all 4 would share the Style.  is there a way to program magento on the front end to display these 4 simple products as one configurable products?  we need to keep them as simple because of the inventory system the store is using.
thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to do it - but I haven't heard of one yet, and I keep up on Magento stuff pretty well.

Unfortunately, Magento does not import configurable products through the backend.  Typically what you have to do is write your own script utilizing the Magento API, or import all the simple products, and then manually (or again, using the API) create the configurable products assigning the simple products to them.